# Sending a HTTPS request and viewing the response

Tags: networking

I am trying to debug the server component of a mobile application. Are there any tools that will allow me to send a HTTPS request and view the response? At the moment I have a Windows computer next to a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) supports HTTPS. It's Windows-only, but you didn't specify a platform. There's plenty of others whatever your platform, though.

Comment: Okay, so you can send a request using the Request Builder tab